# Generate all possible equations from a list of numbers

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, permutations, fastest-code

*This is my first codegolf post so let me know if I have missed anything. Thanks :)*

## **Description**

You are given a list of numbers with `2 < n <= 6` length i.e. [1, 10] or [75, 9, 9, 8, 2, 100]. Given the basic operators `+ - / *` you must try and generate all possible equations. The list of numbers to pull from is: `[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 25, 50, 75, 100]`.

Defining this list **as is** for your program does not count towards the byte count, same goes for defining the list of operators. There are two separate **winning** conditions: 1) Smallest program; 2) Fastest program.

Generating all equations when `n = 6` results in ~200 billion equations. It might be wise to verify that your code works with lower lengths values first, or a subset from the list of numbers.

**Rules**

1. Equations must be in [postfix notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation)
2. No duplicate equations i.e. `1 1 2 + +` and `1 1 2 + +`
3. Handle commutativity i.e. `1 10 + 2 4 + +` and `10 2 1 4 + + +`. Remove commutative equations so only one remains.

**Extra Challenges**

- Calculate all equations, only accepting positive 3 digit solutions. If at any stage during the process the solution becomes negative `1 100 -` or non-int `100 3 /`, stop processing the entire equation and move onto the next equation.

**Final Notes**

Some of you may have recognised the list of numbers from [Countdown](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)) or [Letters and Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Countdown_(game_show)). I myself wrote a [program](https://github.com/Ghrafkly/countdownJava/tree/master/src/main/java/org/countdownJava/Current) (unoptimized, but functional) to calculate all possible 3 digit solutions under the shows rules. It took 90 minutes to run with multithreading, though the slowest part was calculating the equations, not generating them.

Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to the site! While your challenge shows promise, I do think you missed the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc). Please use it to hammer out issues from a challenge before posting. I personally highly recommend answering a few existing challenges (even if your answers are not competitive) before posting your own challenges, to get a feel for what it takes to specify a challenge properly.

Comment: You have a couple of minor English language issues: "i.e." should be "e.g." and "must try and" should be "must try to" (although "must" would be better).

Comment: What exactly does "Defining this list **as is** for your program does not count towards the byte count, same goes for defining the list of operators." mean? Maybe solution will have these definitions intermingled with the rest of the code, making it hard-to-impossible to compute how much space is taken by the definitions. Giving the lists as additional parameters/arguments would make for easier comparison. You *could* also say the lists may be in pre-defined variables, but not all languages have those.

Comment: Regarding "Extra Challenges", is that another required rule, or is it optional? If required, just list it under "Rules". If optional, how does it affect one's score? If it doesn't, there's no point in even mentioning it, as it clearly will lengthen/slow down one's code, so nobody will do it.

Comment: Is the exact sample output necessary, or would less/more whitespace be acceptable? How about outputting as a list like `[1,10,+,2,4,+,+]` or `["1","10","+","2","4","+","+"]`? Are alternative symbols for the four operators allowed, e.g. `+ - × ÷`?

Comment: How do you plan to determine the speed of submissions? Optimising for a specific architecture/CPU instruction set/GPU/etc. can make a big difference. If you plan on running the submissions yourself, are there restrictions on which languages you can run? E.g. some languages can only run on Windows, while might not run on Windows at all.

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the results of each equation, i.e. should each one result in a 3 digit number as it does on Countdown? Countdown doesn't allow for equations that result in floats at any stage of the calculation; are we similarly restricted?

Comment: @Adám defining as is means if you have the number list in the code as [1, 1, 2, 2...,100] then that's as is. If you decide to generate the list dynamically or some other way then that has changed how the list is defined, even though the results are the same. 

You don't need to match samples exactly either. The example you provided is fine. Alternative symbols are allowed as long as they remain the 4 basic operators.

Comment: @Shaggy it does not matter if the equation results in an invalid equation under Countdown's rules. I have edited the challenge to include the calculation as part of the extra challenge however.

Comment: OK, so now you changed the original extra challenge into a proper rule, thus invalidating [an existing answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/260698/43319). On top of that, you've added yet another extra challenge, without specifying if it is required or optional. I recommend deleting your challenge, addressing the raised issue, and then re-opening it, or alternatively, move it to the sanbox as officially recommended.

Comment: [very similar minus the fastest code requirement](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6417/generate-a-valid-equation-using-user-specified-numbers)

Comment: Also related: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/258710/generate-all-possible-equations-with-10-characters

Comment: Maybe you meant `2 <= n <= 6`?

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 31 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
æ¦€œ€`"+-/*"Igãâε¬s`s¦∍S«ðý}ÙIK
```

Goes for the code-golf portion. Brute-force approach, so pretty slow.
Doesn't handle the *Extra Challenge* portion.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDyx41rTk6GUgkKGnr6mspeaYfXnx40bmth9YUJxQDZTt6gw@tPrzh8N7awzM9vf//jzbUMTTQMTeNBQA)

**Explanation:**

```python
æ             # Get the powerset of the (implicit) input-list
 ¦            # Remove the leading empty sublist
  €œ          # Map over each powerset-list, and get all its permutations
    €`        # Flatten the list of lists of lists one level down
"+-/*"        # Push the string of operators
      Ig      # Push the input-length
        ã     # Get the cartesian power of the two
â             # Get the cartesian product of the two lists to create all possible pairs
 ε            # Map over each pair of [list, operator-string]:
  ¬           # Push the head (the list) (without popping)
   s          # Swap so the pair is at the top of the stack again
    `         # Pop and push the list and string separately to the stack
     s        # Swap so the list is at the top of the stack
      ¦       # Remove its first item
       ∍      # Shorten the operator string to the length of this list
        S     # Convert the operator string to a list of characters
         «    # Merge it to the list of integers
          ðý  # Join it by spaces
 }Ù           # After the map: uniquify the results
   IK         # Remove the singular input-integers, since they're not equations
              # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Since 05AB1E uses Reverse Polish/Postfix notation, here the program with additional footer to get the result of each equation: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8LJDyx41rTk6GUgkKGnr6mspeaYfXnx40bmth9YUJxQDZTt6gw@tPrzh8N7awzM9vf@XVdorKdgqKNlX6oXp/I821DE00DE3jQUA).

Comment: Never seen this language before. Though your solution is damn impressive. Well done!

Comment: Note that your solution has become invalid by an edit to the OP.

Comment: *"Since 05AB1E uses Polish/Prefix notation"*: are you sure? I'm pretty sure it uses reverse Polish / postfix notation, where operations come after the operands.

Comment: @Adám I noticed indeed, but thanks for the heads up. I'll see when I have some time to fix it.

Comment: Have you had time to fix this yet?

Comment: @TheFifthMarshal Tbh, I didn't really saw the point since the challenge rules kept changing and it's also closed. Figured I'd wait until it was re-opened, but I guess that won't happen anymore.. :/

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that the question was closed.